Gradle doesnt download dependencies from Nexus
I have got Nexus repository with 2 repos: maven-central(proxy repository to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) and maven-releases.
I want to search artifacts from maven-releases first and then from maven-central. So when i try to build my application with this order:
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://url-to-maven-releases/"
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
    }

    maven {
        url "https://url-to-maven-central"
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
    }
}

In this case Gradle downloads dependencies only from maven-releases and ignores searching in maven-central. But when i try reverse order of repos:
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://url-to-maven-central"
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
    }

    maven {
        url "https://url-to-maven-releases/"
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
    }
}

In this case dependencies downloads correctly. I dont understand why order in this case matters. And how to fix problem for first case.

What is the error message ? The log output?

For 1 case i ve got several same errors with different libraries like that:    > Could not download jcalendar-1.4.jar (com.toedter:jcalendar:1.4)
> Could not get resource 'https://url-to-maven-releases/com/toedter/jcalendar/1.4/jcalendar-1.4.jar'.
> Could not HEAD 'https://url-to-maven-releases/com/toedter/jcalendar/1.4/jcalendar-1.4.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
